# Yii can't find GearmanClient

Tags: php, yii, gearman

I am trying to create tasks using `gearman` using `GearmanClient` class from the gearman-php-extensions. I am able to run below program using command prompt-

```
//php client.php works fine
<?php
$client= new GearmanClient();
$client->addServer();
$task = $client->do("send", "hi");
?>
```

But I wan't to run this code in some `yii controller`. It seems like `yii` is not able to find the path upto `GearmanClient` class, but why?

Also I am writing the `yii` programs in `eclipse`. As `php` command and `eclipse` are both using the same `php` library, my `yii` controller should work fine. Instead my browser gives errors like-

```
PHP warning

include(GearmanClient.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
#plus some warnings and the yii stack trace.
```

Comment: Where is the file located? How are you including it?

Comment: above code is a part of the `protected/controllers/ReportsController.php`. Hope you know the `yii` hierarchy. When I put that 5-line code snippet in client.php, it works with `php <program name>` in `terminal`. But it doesn't run in browser.

Comment: No. I meant, where is the `GearmanClient.php` file located? And how are you including it? You could be specifying the wrong path, which would be the reason why PHP is giving you such error.

Comment: I don't know where the GearmanClient.php is. I have installed the gearman-php-extension using `pecl install gearman` and enabled the gearman support by adding `extension=gearman.so` line to `php.ini` file. I tried to find it with `find / -name GearmanClient.php` but couldn't.

Comment: i suspect php is running as a module of your webserver, if that is the case a restart(of the webserver) is needed, to load the new php.ini settings. to check this check the out put of `phpinfo()` in your page, and see if the gearman extension has been loaded

Comment: my `phpinfo()` doesn't have `gearman`. But running it with `php client.php` works fine. But can't run it in browser.

Comment: command line php will load the latest php.ini and execute the script and exit, but webserver module keeps the old php process running to handle php requests. did you try the restart? which is your webserver?

Comment: @bool.dev, Yes you are right. command line php shows - `gearman support => enabled  
libgearman version => 0.32`.  but browser doesn't; event after restarting webserver. Running it on `nginx`.

Comment: ok, so can you tell me your nginx configuration? are you using any fcgi process? php-fpm maybe? if yes then you'll have to restart that process, basically whatever process is handling your php requests needs to be restarted.

Comment: @bool.dev, You are great. +1 for you.Did `sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm reload` and it works. Put it in answer.

Comment: i just answered, thanks for your kind words :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because, the process that is handling the php files is not updated with the latest php.ini configuration. So you just need to restart that process.

Therefore:

1. If php handler is running as a web server module, then you'll need to restart the web server.
2. If you have php running as a cgi process, then you'll need to restart that process.